# How do I run a commandline program without popping up the cmd.exe window?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, clr

I mostly use bash and perl and use Linux as my primary OS but now I'm on windows and playing around with C++ for the first time. Like a lot of Linux apps out there, I decided to keep the cli and gui elements separately.

I now have my CLI program working and I need to get started with writing a simple frontend to it. All that the frontend does is launch the cli app with a set of options and it should display the output from the program in a textbox and keep appending to it as the program outputs more and more text. The cli program is completely automated and runs on its own and there is no user interaction required after the program starts.

Can someeone show some sample code of launching a cli application without popping up the cmd.exe window or link me to some simple opensoure program similar to this so I can see how they've done it? The CLI program is a long running process. What do I need to do make sure it doesn't freeze the gui?

I'm not sure if I should use CLR or Native Win32 for the frontend. I've seen programs written in .NET and the menus look ugly.

Comment: *I've seen programs written in .NET and the menus look ugly.* - That's like saying that all the oil paintings you've seen are ugly so you will only paint with water-based. Here is a list of books you might gain some insight from: http://www.amazon.com/Books-on-Critical-Thinking/lm/3LLRK1YVHX3IO

Comment: I meant the built-in menu renderers are ugly and the extra effort spent on writing a custom renderer to make it look normal might be better spent on writing a native win32 app.

Comment: There are at least four GUI frameworks in the .NET platform: Asp.Net, WinForms, WPF, and Silverlight. WinForms uses the exact same native win32 controls for menus (and every thing else) that a native app would. WPF makes customizing the look of everything very simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you choose to use .NET libraries in your UI controller you can use System.Diagnostics.Process to create the process and you can set ProcessStartInfo options to redirect StdOut so that you can read from it. There is an example on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.redirectstandardoutput.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [CHP](http://www.commandline.co.uk/chp/) for running your application (CLI or windowed) in invisible window. Its usage is trivial:

```
CHP yourprogram.exe
```

And you can investigate its source, if you would like to know how it's done.

Comment: I'm not sure how to redirect STDOUT after looking at its source but this tool is still useful. I'm gonna use it for running cli apps in the background on startup. Thanks. :)